# Updating from iOS 4.x without iTunes

Tags: upgrade

My old computer in which I had iTunes on is broken.  So my question is, are there any other ways of updating an iPad without having iTunes? If not, are there any stores that will do it?

Comment: What iPad version have you got? Do you want to update to the 4.3 exactly or the latest version?

Comment: Hey there thank you for replying....I have 4.0 I think...I would rather update to the latest version, but I am not sure how to to this without iTunes

Answer (score 1):

While **iOS 5** does, [indeed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4623), support *iTunesless* software update, previous versions don't, which is your case.

Therefore I suggest you to go to any **Apple Store**, which will certainly help you with your issue, or try any other **Apple Retailler**.

Comment: I Will try that...thank you so much for your help. I was getting worried there weren't many options....now my next step is to find a CLOSE apple store....could be hours away....lol maybe they will let me send my iPad in....don't know. ;~}....not sure where the retailers are ....maybe walmart...don't know if they can help, but I know they sell them.                           Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Now, if you have time to answer this one....lol.  Do you know if after I get the iOS 5....will I have to keep going back for updates or will my iPad be able to update on it's own?......may be a stupid question, but I know very little about this.

Comment: @Shaw The link on my answer shows how, after having **iOS 5**, install iOS Update without iTunes. :) Please accept the answer if it was helpful, as it will mark the question as solved.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the trouble, and thanks for all of your help ;~}